# Null pointer exception in getApplicationContext()?

Tags: android, android-context

I'm making an app that requires the GPS position of the user to be found before proceeding. I'm doing this by implementing the LocationListener interface.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(loc!=null){
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        text = "My current location is: " + "Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting a NullPointerException in the getApplicationContext() method. I also tried MyClass.this, but same result. The toast works fine when I display it in the onCreate. I looked up other questions similar to this one, but none of the solutions worked. I'm using a setContentView in the onCreate, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gpslocation);
}
```

The logcat shows this:

```
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at emergency.app.MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(MyLocationListener.java:53)
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:227)
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:160)
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:176)
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-14 14:05:48.396: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone tell me how to overcome this? I'm a beginner in android, so I really need help!

Comment: what changes you med...can you share...so that we also come to know

Comment: Could you put your logcat?

Comment: I fixed a mistake I had made in the question. The problem is still there. And I've added the logcat too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code work in my phone and give me location point in Toast.

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this, (String) msg.obj,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    System.out.println("onLocationChanged :");
    if (location != null) {
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();
        String text = "My current location is: " + "Latitude = "
                + location.getLatitude() + "Longitude = "
                + location.getLongitude();
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = 0;
        msg.obj = text;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
```

}

also add permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: if you add more functionality then show http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: I'm using telnet to change the gps position, by establishing a connection to the simulator and then using 'geo fix' to set the position. But now, even the onLocationChange method is not getting called. I'm using a different system now. Does that matter?

Comment: PS: Since I don't have the laptop I began my project on, I made a new project on a different laptop, just to check this code.

Comment: When I did the same thing on the original laptop, I used to get an exception.

Comment: Now I'm getting an IllegalArgumentException in this line:
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

Comment: It worked after I changed NETWORK_PROVIDER to GPS_PROVIDER. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

**Use the current context (=this)** instead of the application wide context.

```
Toast.makeText(this,text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, (String) msg.obj,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
};


public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(loc!=null){
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        text = "My current location is: " + "Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();

        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what=0;
        msg.obj= text;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2130562 plz try getApplicationContext() where YourActivity.this.

if this not work then , your toast show after that finish your activity.

can you put your activity ?? 
bcoz easy for me to find error...

Comment: getApplicationContext() didn't work. And what do you mean by finish activity after showing toast? Could you explain further?

Comment: @user2130562 can you put your activity class ???
if yes then put, it helpful to find error.
thnx

Comment: There's nothing else in the class apart from the onCreate and the LocationListener functions. Except for onLocationChanged, all the other functions are empty.